# WMS on flutter map return empty images

Tags: flutter, geoserver, fluttermap

I installed GeoServer and For test, I added a layer like this:
[image]

On the flutter side, I am using flutter_map :

```
return FlutterMap(
  mapController: controller,
  options: MapOptions(
    zoom: 6,
    minZoom: 2.0,
    maxZoom: 18.0,
    center: widget.point,
    onPositionChanged: widget.onPositionChanged,
   
  ),
  nonRotatedChildren: [
    AttributionWidget.defaultWidget(
      source: 'OpenStreetMap contributors',
      onSourceTapped: null,
    ),
  ],
  children: [
    TileLayer(
      wmsOptions: WMSTileLayerOptions(
        crs: const Epsg4326(),
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost/geoserver/EazyCityDBWS/wms?',
        layers: ['EazyCityDBWS:Provinces'],
      ),
    ),
    TileLayer(
      urlTemplate: 'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
      subdomains: const ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ),
```

But after running the application I just see the map, not my layer. I checked to inspect tool of the browser :

[image]

All images are empty? Does someone have experience with using WMS on Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like the result one would get if the layer is a "borders" one, rather than a polygon one, and one would still try to apply a polygon style to it.

By SLD specification, if one has a line and applies a polygon style to it, then the line must be closed by connecting its start and end points, and then filling the resulting polygon.

Comment: I applied a polygon to my layer style when publishing https://ibb.co/NmJVMZ5. but I think, My coordinates are multiline strings. Is it possible to show them on a map https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEY5.png @Andrea Aime

Comment: The other problem is here, I cant use both WMSTileLayerOptions and urlTemplate at the same time.